# How to create an folder path alias on ubuntu EC2 instance?

Tags: command-line, bash, amazon-ec2, alias

`ubuntu 18.04 on AWS`

I followed an answer on stackoverflow to create a path alias:

```
nano ~/.bashrc

alias myfolder='/home/xxx/pms'
```

When I try to `cd`

```
cd myfolder
```

I get:

> No such file or Directory

But if I use the path it works.

I am not sure what the issue here is.

TIA

Comment: If you use `alias "myfolder"="cd /home/xxx/pms"` and `source ~/.bashrc` you'll be able to access your folder typing only `myfolder` on the terminal...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## What you're trying

You may be thinking of the term alias as [defined and used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(Mac_OS)) in Mac OS.

For ubuntu the command [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command)#Unix) does something totally different. The command you have used is for creating new commands so you don't have to remember a longer command, or a longer command you type so much it is quicker to type the alias. For example, if I don't want to keep typing this command to launch a program:

`java -jar /usr/local/bin/bfg-1.13.0.jar`

You could create an alias called `bfg` in my Unix profile (or `~/.bashrc` as you have) like this:

`alias bfg='java -jar /usr/local/bin/bfg-1.13.0.jar'`

From now on I can use `bfg` every time I want to run the java program.

## What you really need

In Ubuntu what you're looking for is a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_(Unix)). A symbolic link is created with the `ln` command on Ubuntu (and all other Unix varieties). See the following example.

In the below example you can see a folder that *already exists* called `pms` in my home folder.

Thus its absolute path is `/home/ubuntu/pms`.

```sh
ubuntu@server:~$ ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 25 11:05 pms
```

Now I change to a mother directory where I want the link, what you are thinking of as an alias, and create the *symbolic link* with `ln -s`

```sh
ubuntu@server:~$ cd /tmp/
ubuntu@server:/tmp$ ln -s /home/ubuntu/pms myfolder
```

Now I'm able to change directory to this *alias* as you understand it.

```sh
ubuntu@server:/tmp$ cd myfolder/
ubuntu@server:/tmp/myfolder$ pwd
/tmp/myfolder
```

To be clear, an alias is a completely different thing in Unix & Linux land. The symbolic link I have made can be seen by listing the `/tmp` directory where I created it.

```sh
ubuntu@server:/tmp/myfolder$ cd /tmp
ubuntu@server:/tmp$ ls -l
total 16
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu   16 Mar 25 11:06 myfolder -> /home/ubuntu/pms
```

The contents of the `/tmp/myfolder` are one and the same as `/home/ubuntu/pms`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Now when I make changes to certain files using the above link, the changes will carry through?

Comment: Yes. Files and folders seen and created in the symlinked folder (from the example) `/tmp/myfolder` and in the original `/home/ubuntu/pms` are actually the same files on the disk.